# How to apply Parallax Scroll in div visible on screen

Tags: jquery, html, css, parallax

I have multiple divs with images inside. I want to apply the parallax to the image inside the div.
However, if I set the parallax scroll to the images, the images at the bottom of the screen make a white space inside the div since images scroll up to high.

This is my code so far.

HTML

```
  <div class="workImg">
    <img class="inWorkImg" src="img/08.png"/>
  </div>

  <div class="workImg">
    <img class="inWorkImg" src="img/09.png"/>
  </div>

  <div class="workImg">
    <img class="inWorkImg" src="img/10.png"/>
  </div>

  <div class="workImg">
    <img class="inWorkImg" src="img/11.png"/>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
.workImg{
 position: absolute;
  width: 80%;
  height: 230px;
  bottom: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.inWorkImg {
  object-fit: cover;
  height: 110%;
}
```

JQUERY

```
var parallaxElements = $('.inWorkImg'),
  parallaxQuantity = parallaxElements.length;
var visible = isInViewport(this)


$(window).on('scroll', function () {

  if(visible) {

    window.requestAnimationFrame(function () {

      for (var i = 0; i < parallaxQuantity; i++) {
        var currentElement = parallaxElements.eq(i);
        var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop();

        currentElement.css({
          'transform': 'translate3d(0,' + scrolled * -0.06 + 'px, 0)'
        });

      }

    });
  }

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you don't have to use jQuery for that, but use pure css like that -

Instead of `img` tag, those divs will get an `background-image` property.

```
 <div class="workImg1"></div>
 <div class="workImg2"></div>
 <div class="workImg3"></div>
 <div class="workImg4"></div>
```

And CSS will look like that -

```
.workImg1, .workImg2, .workImg3, .workImg4 {
      /* Set a specific height */
      min-height: 500px; 

      /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
      background-attachment: fixed;
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
}
.workImg1 {
          /* The image used */
          background-image: url("IMG_URL");
}
.workImg2 {
          /* The image used */
          background-image: url("IMG_URL");
}
.workImg3 {
          /* The image used */
          background-image: url("IMG_URL");
}
.workImg4 {
          /* The image used */
          background-image: url("IMG_URL");
}
```

Comment: I don't see how this creates a parallax scroll?

Comment: This does creates a parallax scroll but, it makes the image too big to be shown fully in the parent div... I think this is only for the full-screen parallax scroll.